# Count total rows that exists in a table but not in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables:

#### Booking

```
    AWBNO       BYHUB         ENTRYDATE
     111         HO            2017-02-02
     222         HO            2017-02-02
     333         HO            2017-02-02
     444         HO            2017-02-02
     555         HO            2017-02-02
```

#### Receiving

```
   AWBNO        FROMHUB         ENTRYDATE
   111            AP             2017-02-04
   222            AP             2017-02-04
   333            AP             2017-02-04
```

#### Status

```
   AWBNO       TOHUB          STATUS             ENTRYDATE     
    111         HO            DELIVERD           2017-02-05
    222         HO            DELIVERD           2017-02-05
    333         HO            DELIVERD           2017-02-05
    444         HO            DELIVERD           2017-02-05
    555         HO            DELIVERD           2017-02-05
```

I want to count the  total delivered `AWBNO` that don't exists in `Receiving` table but exists in `Booking` table.
I'd like the output in this format:

#### Output

```
 TOTAL_BOOKING       TOTAL_RECEVING        TOTAL_RECEVING_FAIL      TOTAL_STATUS      TOTAL_STATUS_DELIVERD_WITHOUT_RECEVING
     5                    3                      2                      5                          2
```

Comment: Question was all caps and not clearly understandable. fixed formatting and generalized the issue a bit

Answer (score 0):

**This Query work in proper way but when I used in hug (big data) data then it is take more time.**

**Please suggest me in another way**.

```
 Select count(B.awbno) TOTAL_BOOKING,

 count(R.awbno) TOTAL_RECEIVING,

 count(S.awbno) total_status,

 count(B.awbno) - count(R.awbno) total_receiving_fail,

 count(case when S.status='deliverd' and R.awbno is null then 1 end) TOTAL_STATUS_DELIVERD_WITHOUT_RECEVING

from booking B left join report R on B.awbno = R.awbno

left join status S on B.awbno = S.awbno
```